# Access function params inside of JS DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Can you please help me figure out what I am missing. I have my code wired up as below. I am creating DOM via JS and I want to access the parameters in the function creating it but so far I haven't found a way around.

```
var createRow = function (employee, index) {
        var newRow = AddRow('employeesTable');
        addCellsToRow(newRow, [
            ....
            '<input type="text" value="commission" onkeypress="userMath(event, index)">',
            ....
        ])
    }
```

But when I do keypress the var `index` is `not found` and I have tried using `this.index` and it goes `undefined`. How best can I go about this?

Comment: use concatenation? `'<input type="text" value="commission" onkeypress="userMath('+employee +', ' +index +')">'` (assuming `event` is supposed to be `employee`)

Comment: ```<input type="text" value="commission" onkeypress="userMath(event, ${index})">```

Comment: let me try both ways, thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Try with [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
`<input type="text" value="commission" onkeypress="userMath(event, ${index})">`,
```

**OR:** With string concatenation

```
'<input type="text" value="commission" onkeypress="userMath(event, '+index+')>'
```

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, string concetanation did the job